# What does the statement "delegates are secure" mean?

Tags: c#, .net, security, delegates

In the [C# documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx) for delegates, it says *"A delegate is a reference type that can be used to encapsulate a named or an anonymous method. Delegates are similar to function pointers in C++; however, delegates are type-safe and **secure**"*

My question is, what do they mean by a delegate it "***secure***"?

Comment: Looks like that part was written by marketing... it doesn't mean *anything* at all.  Security is in a design, not a language feature.

Comment: not a language feature? of course it is also language dependent, look at ADA

Comment: @BenVoigt Actually it does mean something. It is impossible for a delegate to point to an invalid address, which can happen in C. As such they are safe to use - you will not jump into some random memory.

Comment: @TomTom: Wild delegates are at least as likely as wild function pointers.  (Possibly more likely, since when using delegates with p/invoke, there's no type cross-checking possible between caller and callee)  C++ function pointers are perfectly safe unless you start casting them (always a bad idea), and delegates also run into trouble when you disable the type system.

Comment: @BenVoigt No, they are not. PInvoke is a fringe case. Casting may be a bad idea, it is totally save in C#. Plus there is secucirty, such as CAS (Code Access Security) which also plays into delegates.

Comment: Whew, I though they introduced _yet another_ keyword...

Comment: @TomTom: C# is not safe either.  You can cast pointers inside an unsafe block, you can use `Marshal.Copy`.  Many ways to overwrite memory bypassing type safety.  I'm going back to what I said when I commented on one of the answers... you have to do something spectacularly stupid to run into trouble in either C++ or C#.

Comment: Well, tons of people in C disagree with you, pointer corruption is an issue there, and unsafe blocks in C# are seriously not worth even talking about becauset he definition of unsafe is invalidating safety.

Comment: @TomTom: None of the usual pointer mistakes (use after delete, indexing off an array, etc) apply to function pointers.  I do wish people wouldn't just repeat what "tons of people" say, and actually try to understand the technical issues themselves.

Comment: @TomTom: But why are we arguing about *type safety*, when this question is specifically about the other part of the quote?

Answer (score 8):

Delegates enforce type-safe calls to methods. This typically works by static type checking performed by the compiler. But is not the only way, you can use `Delegate.DynamicInvoke()` to bypass compiler type checking. An example:

```
using System;

class Program {
    delegate void foo(long arg);
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var obj = new Example();
        var dlg = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(foo), obj, "Target");
        dlg.DynamicInvoke(42);
    }
}

class Example {
    private long field;
    public void Target(long arg) {
        field = arg;
    }
}
```

Now start tinkering with this code, the kind of things you can do to try to fool the type system:

- change the foo delegate declaration
- pass a different delegate type as the 1st argument
- pass an object of a different class as the 2nd argument
- change the target method name
- pass an argument of a different type in the `DynamicInvoke` call
- pass a different set of arguments in the `DynamicInvoke` call

All of these attempts will compile without complaint. None of them will execute, you'll get runtime exceptions. That's what makes delegates secure, you cannot use them to invoke a method that will leave the stack imbalanced or induce the target method to access stack locations that are not initialized or not part of the activation frame. The traditional way malware hijacks code. No such runtime checking exists in C or C++, their compilers performs static checking only and that can be bypassed with a simple cast.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is, what do they mean by a delagate is "secure"?
>
> **Functions called with a delegate are given the security context of the caller, which prevents a delegate from performing a task not
>   available to a lower-privilege caller.** Delegates can be initialized
>   with pointers to functions that are implemented anywhere. The only
>   limitation is the signature. Callers need to be careful when invoking
>   delegates containing function pointers to unknown sources, where there
>   could be unexpected implementation. Use code access security to
>   protect delegates.

Credit:  http://etutorials.org/Programming/programming+microsoft+visual+c+sharp+2005/Part+III+More+C+Language/Chapter+8+Delegates+and+Events/

Comment: That explains how delegates, if not used correctly, introduce insecurities.  Quite the opposite of the claim in the question.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Actually it's right on point with regards to **Secure**. "a delegate are given the security context of the caller, which prevents a delegate from performing a task not available to a lower-privilege caller." which means they are Secure

Comment: That's not a difference from C++, which the quote in the question claims.

Comment: I'm not saying it is, apparently, the author didn't quite know how to word that part.  But it does answer the question "My question is, what do they mean by a delagate it "secure"?"

Answer (score 2):

In this context, I think secure means that a delegate cannot hold an invalid value. This probably overlaps a little with the type-safe part.

Answer (score 2):

It means you cannot "mess around" like you could in C/C++, making the function pointer point to invalid areas of memory or worse, to malicious code.

Answer (score 2):

It's comparing them to function pointers in C++, which can be used to "blow your leg off" as the man said.

Comment: C++ function pointers are actually very safe.  You have to do something spectacularly stupid to get a wild function pointer (on the other hand, data pointers often run into use-after-delete, leaks, etc.)